# How to find out the longest pattern in a string

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to find out the longest pattern in a string. For example, I have string= 'aabbbcc', and let it return 'bbb' which is longest pattern. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking hypothetically?  Answer: empirically look at the string and determine which one has the most consecutive identical characters.

Comment: What do you mean by "pattern"? Do you mean "repetitions of a single letter"?

Comment: You only tagged this with "algorithm", but you could use an example, with more than one sample input and output. Pattern is a very broad word-do you want something that is just to match repeating occurrence of a specific letter, or do you want something more intelligent? It sounds like a regex would fix your situation either way, but idk which language to go for.

Comment: Seriously? 7 questions asked, 0 accepted... Please read the FAQ and trying and become a better citizen on SO. And it should all start with posting better, well-thought-out questions. This may also help: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: what do you exactly mean with pattern? in your example string i could say the longest pattern is `aabbbcc` as well

Comment: Is this homework? Take a shot at it and post what you've tried first. I'd susggest based on what you have said that you start by looking at run-length encoding for ideas.

Comment: This question might be more welcome on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It could be c#, yes, just repeated characters. If it is acacacbcbc, possible as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You .NET could accomplish this easily using the following,

```
string s = "aabbbcc";
var countByObject = s.GroupBy(q => q).OrderByDescending(q1 => q1.Count())
                                     .Select(q2 => new { Letter = q2.Key, CountOfObjects = q2.Count() })
                                     .ToList();
```

...where `countByObject` is a list of anonymous objects containing a `Letter` and corresponding `Count`.  Implemented:

```
s.GroupBy(q => q).OrderByDescending(q1 => q1.Count())
                 .Select(q2 => new { Letter = q2.Key, CountOfObjects = q2.Count() })
                 .ToList().ForEach(q3=>{
                       Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}",q3.Letter, q3.CountOfObjects));   
                 });
```

...prints out:

```
b 3
a 2
c 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say the language... But you can use a **for** to compare each letter of the string with the last one. Each time that is equal, you can add 1 to a variable... At the end, you just need to get the biggest variable... (You can do it just using two variable)